# Job/Queue management in Postgres using PGQ

Tags: postgresql

I am trying out the PGQ extension of Postgres. I am currently using PGQ v3.5 and Postgres 15. I am trying out a test email sending event and I have created a queue and registered a consumer. My consumer is a custom function. However , I am unable to get the consumer to process the event.Please see code below. I am not sure what I am missing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT pgq.create_queue('email_queue4');

-- Define custom function to process events
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION email_consumer4(queue_name text, batch_id integer, batch_size integer)
RETURNS SETOF pgq.event AS $$
DECLARE
    event pgq.event;
    --email_data jsonb;
BEGIN
    -- Process each event in the batch
    FOR event IN SELECT * FROM pgq.get_batch_events(queue_name, batch_id) LOOP
        -- Extract email data from event
       --email_data := event.data;
       
       -- send_email_function(email_data->>'to', email_data->>'subject', email_data->>'body');
        
        
        -- Send email using some email sending library
        PERFORM send_email('no-reply@tx.fixedopspc.com', '001d0b9ed9cc81f06a4324019f308301-27a562f9-1b88d500', 'smtp.mailgun.org', '587',
                'priyadarshini.guptan@citrusinformatics.com', 'Test Email', 'Test Success', '{}', NULL, NULL, NULL);
        
        -- Mark event as processed
        PERFORM pgq.finish_event(event.ev_id);
        
        -- Return event to indicate successful processing
        RETURN NEXT event;
    END LOOP;
    
    -- No more events in batch, so return null
    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


SELECT pgq.register_consumer('email_queue4', 'email_consumer4');

-- Add event to queue
SELECT pgq.insert_event('email_queue4','email_event','Test 1');

select batch_id 
        from pgq.next_batch_info('email_queue4', 'email_consumer4');
        
select pgq.next_batch('email_queue4', 'email_consumer4');
```

The consumer function is not getting triggered. No email is being sent.